# Google Maps v3 Markers not Stacking/Plotting Properly on Zoom Out

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, latitude-longitude, markers

When zooming out, markers don't always stack.  Some rental properties are part of a rental complex, same building, so I would think that they would stack as you zoom out, or even initial for that matter, but don't.

You can check out one of the maps here: 
http://www.oxfordrealtynd.com/rent/?p=1&bedrooms=&city=Grand+Forks

Markers are also not being redrawn correctly either.  If you view the map of the first property in the results with the link above and zoom out you will notice two red markers to the left of the orange marker that don't stay within the city block they are on.

If you zoom waaay out all the markers are plotted west of the city.

You can see the non-stacking issue with this rental property, 2951 24th Ave S, which should be  2nd in the list if the link above is used.

As far as how I'm plotting the markers I build an xml file of marker data off the the search parameters.  Then I plot only the markers that appear within the bounds of the map.  Markers are deleted and redrawn with an event listener added to the `idle` event.

I'm at a loss and haven't been able to find any relevant issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the `markerImage`'s is wrong.

The 4th parameter(anchor) has to be the same for all markerImage's:

```
new google.maps.Point( 10, 25 )
```

[**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/uRtcw/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/uRtcw/)

Comment: Thank you sir, I must have miss read something in the docs and though it was based on the images position in the sprite.  Now onto fixing the stacking.

Comment: The documentation is not very clear related to the use of sprites, so it may be misunderstood.